# 5 Feb 16:53:26 ntpdate[414]: no server suitable for synchronization found

Tags: proxy, firewall, ntp, embedded-linux

I want to setup ntp in beaglebone based custom board.

/etc/ntp.conf file content is as mentioned below

```
driftfile /var/run/ntp.drift

server pool.ntp.org
server 1.in.pool.ntp.org
server 1.asia.pool.ntp.org
server 2.asia.pool.ntp.org

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
#restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
#restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
#restrict ::1
```

when i run command `ntpdate -d 77.235.14.49` i get following output

```
5 Feb 17:07:42 ntpdate[429]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349 Thu Jan 23 08:13:41 UTC 2014 (1)
Looking for host 77.235.14.49 and service ntp
host found : 77.235.14.49
transmit(77.235.14.49)
transmit(77.235.14.49)
transmit(77.235.14.49)
transmit(77.235.14.49)
transmit(77.235.14.49)
77.235.14.49: Server dropped: no data
server 77.235.14.49, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [77.235.14.49], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036 11:58:16.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036 11:58:16.000
transmit timestamp:  d69ca10c.1f050e72  Wed, Feb  5 2014 17:07:48.121
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

 5 Feb 17:07:50 ntpdate[429]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

when i ping the same ip it works fine

```
ping 77.235.14.49
PING 77.235.14.49 (77.235.14.49): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 77.235.14.49: seq=0 ttl=47 time=268.123 ms
64 bytes from 77.235.14.49: seq=1 ttl=48 time=262.530 ms
64 bytes from 77.235.14.49: seq=2 ttl=48 time=263.236 ms
64 bytes from 77.235.14.49: seq=3 ttl=47 time=266.751 ms
64 bytes from 77.235.14.49: seq=4 ttl=48 time=262.649 ms
64 bytes from 77.235.14.49: seq=5 ttl=48 time=262.303 ms
64 bytes from 77.235.14.49: seq=6 ttl=48 time=262.409 ms
^C
--- 77.235.14.49 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 262.303/264.000/268.123 ms
```

I referred some of the questions in QA websites and they talk about firewall, I don't know how do i make those (firewall or related )changes in the embedded Linux board?

Board is connected to organization's LAN and gets ip by dhcp. Can there be a problem with respect to proxy.

If required where can i put proxy settings in Board?

Answer (score -1):

Try using cntlm for proxy authentication. For more information refer: http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/